# Azure Blob Storage for Apache Cordova App

Tags: cordova, azure

I have an Apache Cordova (PhoneGap) application, and now I want to upload: photos, audio and video to Azure; reviewing a [post](http://aminespinoza.com/subir-una-imagen-al-almacenamiento-de-azure-usando-windows-phone/) I found that it can be done with the Azure Storage Service, but I can't find an article or example code to do this with an application Cordova (PhoneGap).

Can you upload such files with an application (PhoneGap) Cordova?

Comment: Azure Blob Storage is not the same thing as 'blob' in Cordova, which is related to HTML FILE API's Blob. http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/

Comment: @JamesWong [Azure Blog Storage](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/storage/) is a service of the server-side. From what I see, FileSystem APIs is for local storage.

Comment: thanks for the link. I am well aware what is Microsoft Azure, we have been pitched by MS this year, we didn't like it. But anyways, can you clarify your question in order for us to help you? Are you looking to upload files directly to MS Azure Blob Storage? or are you looking to manipulate it from within Cordova.

Comment: Hi, I am looking to upload pictures from a Phonegap/Cordova application to windows azure blob storage. @JamesWong Indeed this is what Pit is asking. How can we upload an image from our JS to Azure ?

Comment: @JamesWong Upload Files directly to Azure and manipilate it from with Cordova. Today I capture the image, audio and video; then I have a path, which is where is the generated file. Now I only need to manipulate that file, I think you have to convert it to base64 to upload it to Azure

Comment: @SaniYusuf It is correct.

Comment: @Pit You can actually get the base64 of an image with Cordova. this is how far I have gone but I am yet to get to the stage where I upload it to the Azure Blob

Comment: @SaniYusuf You use capture in Cordova and Base64? You have something that can be seen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solid answer end to end with project sample.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/writingdata_services/archive/2014/12/15/epic-saga-final-chapter-success-or-how-to-upload-images-to-azure-from-a-cordova-app.aspx

For the sake of making sure a dead link doesn't leave someone high and dry later, here is the code.

**The following, which replaces the original submit event handler for the Add button, takes the picture, uses info from the captured image to set some properties on the item, then calls insertNewItemWithUpload():**

```
// Handle insert--this replaces the existing handler.
$('#add-item').submit(function (evt) {
    var textbox = $('#new-item-text'),
        itemText = textbox.val();
    if (itemText !== '') {

        var newItem = { text: itemText, complete: false };
        // Do the capture before we do the insert. If user cancels, just continue.
        // Launch device camera application to capture a single image.                
        navigator.device.capture.captureImage(function (mediaFiles) {
            if (mediaFiles) {
                // Set a reference to the captured file.
                var capturedFile = mediaFiles[0];

                // Set the properties we need on the inserted item.
                newItem.containerName = "todoitemimages";
                newItem.resourceName = capturedFile.name;

                // Insert the item and upload the blob.
                insertNewItemWithUpload(newItem, capturedFile);
            }

        }, function () {
            // Insert the item but not the blob.
            insertNewItemWithUpload(newItem, null);
        }, { limit: 1 });
    }
    textbox.val('').focus();
    evt.preventDefault();
});
```

**The following insertNewItemWithUpload() function sends the new TodoItem object to Mobile Services:**

```
// Insert a new item, then also upload a captured image if we have one.
var insertNewItemWithUpload = function (newItem, capturedFile) {
    // Do the insert so that we can get the SAS query string from Blob storage.
    todoItemTable.insert(newItem).then(function (item) {
        // If we have obtained an SAS, then upload the image to Blob storage.
        if (item.sasQueryString !== undefined) {

            insertedItem = item;
            readImage(capturedFile);
        }
    }, handleError).then(refreshTodoItems, handleError);
}
```

**When the item being inserted has a containerName field, the following insert script in the mobile service (basically the same as the tutorials) generates an SAS, is used to upload the image to Azure:**

```
var azure = require('azure');
var qs = require('querystring');
var appSettings = require('mobileservice-config').appSettings;

function insert(item, user, request) {
  // Get storage account settings from app settings. 
  var accountName = appSettings.STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME;
  var accountKey = appSettings.STORAGE_ACCOUNT_ACCESS_KEY;

  var host = accountName + '.blob.core.windows.net';

  if ((typeof item.containerName !== "undefined") && (
  item.containerName !== null)) {
      // Set the BLOB store container name on the item, which must be lowercase.
      item.containerName = item.containerName.toLowerCase();

      // If it does not already exist, create the container 
      // with public read access for blobs.        
      var blobService = azure.createBlobService(accountName, accountKey, host);
      blobService.createContainerIfNotExists(item.containerName, {
          publicAccessLevel: 'blob'
      }, function(error) {
          if (!error) {

              // Provide write access to the container for the next 5 mins.        
              var sharedAccessPolicy = {
                  AccessPolicy: {
                      Permissions: azure.Constants.BlobConstants.SharedAccessPermissions.WRITE,
                      Expiry: new Date(new Date().getTime() + 5 * 60 * 1000)
                  }
              };

              // Generate the upload URL with SAS for the new image.
              /*var sasQueryUrl = 
              blobService.generateSharedAccessSignature(item.containerName, 
              item.resourceName, sharedAccessPolicy);*/

              var sasQueryUrl = 
              blobService.generateSharedAccessSignature(item.containerName, 
              '', sharedAccessPolicy);

              // Set the query string.
              item.sasQueryString = qs.stringify(sasQueryUrl.queryString);

              // Set the full path on the new new item, 
              // which is used for data binding on the client. 
              item.imageUri = sasQueryUrl.baseUrl + sasQueryUrl.path + '/' 
                  + item.resourceName;          

          } else {
              console.error(error);
          }
          request.execute();
      });
  } else {
      request.execute();
  }
}
```

**With the SAS provided by the mobile service, it is pretty easy to upload the JPEG file using a PUT request, with the SAS as a query string. It turns out the best way to do this is to use a good ol’ XMLHttpRequest. First, I needed to get the locally stored image, which gets saved by the camera capture operation. The following code uses the capture image metadata to get the local file and read it into an array buffer:**

```
// This function is called to get the newly captured image
// file and read it into an array buffer. 
function readImage(capturedFile) {
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(capturedFile.fullPath, function (fileEntry) {
        fileEntry.file(function (file) {
            // We need a FileReader to read the captured file.
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onloadend = readCompleted;
            reader.onerror = fail;

            // Read the captured file into a byte array.
            // This function is not currently supported on Windows Phone.
            reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
        }, fail);
    });
}
```

**When the read operation completes, the binary array data is sent as the body of the XMLHttpRequest:**

```
// This function gets called when the reader is done loading the image
// and it is sent via an XMLHttpRequest to the Azure Storage Blob service.
var readCompleted = function (evt) {
    if (evt.target.readyState == FileReader.DONE) {

        // The binary data is the result.
        var requestData = evt.target.result;

        // Build the request URI with the SAS, which gives us permissions to upload.
        var uriWithAccess = insertedItem.imageUri + "?" + insertedItem.sasQueryString;
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.onerror = fail;
        xhr.onloadend = uploadCompleted;
        xhr.open("PUT", uriWithAccess);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('x-ms-blob-type', 'BlockBlob');
        xhr.setRequestHeader('x-ms-blob-content-type', 'image/jpeg');
        xhr.send(requestData);
    }
}
```

**With the difficult uploading part of the sample complete, the final thing to do was to make sure that the images were being displayed with their items. I first had to tweak the CSS to remove the limit on height of items in the list, then I updated the**

```
function refreshTodoItems() {
    $('#summary').html("Loading...");
    var query = todoItemTable;//.where({ complete: false });

    // Execute the query and then generate the array list.
    query.read().then(function (todoItems) {
        var listItems = $.map(todoItems, function (item) {
            var listItem = $('<li>')
                .attr('data-todoitem-id', item.id)
                .append($('<button class="item-delete">Delete</button>'))
                .append($('<input type="checkbox" class="item-complete">').prop('checked', item.complete))
                .append($('<div>').append($('<input class="item-text">').val(item.text)));

            // Only add the image if the URL exists.
            if (item.imageUri)
            {                      
                listItem.append($('<img>').attr('src', item.imageUri));
            }
            return listItem;
        });

        $('#todo-items').empty().append(listItems).toggle(listItems.length > 0);
        $('#summary').html('<strong>' + todoItems.length + '</strong> item(s)');

        var width = $('#todo-items').width();

        $('#todo-items img').css({
            'max-width': width, 'height': 'auto'
        });

    }, handleError);
}
```

Comment: As a note to others in the future, this method will not work with uploading files in a multipart/form-data connection. You will need to wire your code through probably the Cordova file-transfer plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a working solution. But actually, I did not need to use a blob storage. I actually just sent the bae64 string directly to azure as a string and retrieved it in my Phonegap app when needed.

For me, this was even cheaper and less duplicative as I did not need a blob as i just put the base64 string in the field where I would have put the blob url. Simple yet very effective

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I'm looking for a solution with Blob Storage.